# Updating permalink structure using 'post_link' filter results in 404 error for posts

Tags: posts, permalinks, filters

I am trying to modify the permalink structure of the default post type `post` to include custom taxonomy terms. Here's my function and filter:

```
/**
 * Add media type slug to URL structure for posts
 */
add_filter( 'post_link', 'xx_filter_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

function xx_filter_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {

  if ( false === strpos( $link, '%media_type%') )
    return $link;

  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'media-type');
  // set media type; if none is found, provide a default value.
  if ( 0 < count($terms) ) {
    // Get first term in array
    $first_term = $terms[0]->term_id;
    // Create a string to represent hierarchy of terms
    $media_type = get_taxonomy_parents( $first_term, 'media-type', false, '/', true );
    // Remove trailing slash
    $media_type = trim( $media_type, '/' );
  } else {
    $media_type = 'articles';
  }
  $media_type = urlencode($media_type);
  $media_type = str_replace( '%2F', '/' , $media_type );
  $link = str_replace( '%media_type%', $media_type , $link );

  return $link;
}
```

In `Settings > Permalinks` I am using a custom structure of `/insights/%media_type%/%postname%/`.

The post URL is formatted correctly after resetting permalinks, but when I navigate to the link I get a 404 page. Sad panda.

How am I being a dummy and how should I be smarter so this works?

**EDIT:** After reading a bit of the codex, I realized that I forgot to add the rewrite rule. That said, I'm still missing something. I updated the function above ever so slightly and I set `hierarchical` to `true` in the `rewrite` property when I registered the taxonomy. Now my posts work fine unless they are assigned to multiple taxonomy terms in the hierarchy (for example, `xx.com/insights/parent/post` works, but `xx.com/insights/parent/child/post`still gives me a 404). My regex skills are pretty weak, so wonder if I'm missing something there to account for the hierarchy.

```
add_action( 'init', 'xx_media_type_rewrite_tag', 10, 0 );

function xx_media_type_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag( '%media_type%', '([^&]+)', 'media-type=' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^insights/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?media_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]','top' );
}
```

Comment: Did you [add `media_type` to the list of query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)?

Comment: I did not. After reading through the codex and a few samples, I modified my function a bit:

Comment: @Milo See above for my modified filter function and where I set `media_type` as an acceptable query var. I feel like I'm really close here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, and while I'm not convinced it's the simplest or most performant solution, it does the job. If someone some day takes interest in this and has a cleaner method, I'd love to revisit it. For now, here's what worked:

In my `register_taxonomy` function, set the rewrites as such:

```
'rewrite'             => array(
  'slug'                => 'media-type',
  'hierarchical'        => true,
),
```

Then, set rewrite rules for posts:

```
add_action( 'init', 'xx_media_type_rewrite_tag', 10, 0 );

function xx_media_type_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag( '%media_type%', '([^&]+)', 'media-type=' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^insights/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?media_type=$matches[1]&media_type=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]','top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^insights/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?media_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]','top' );
}
```

Then, filter the post link (this the part I'd imagine could look a lot cleaner if I knew what I was doing):

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'xx_filter_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

function xx_filter_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {

  if ( false === strpos( $link, '%media_type%') )
    return $link;

  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'media-type');

  // set media type; if none is found, provide a default value.
  if ( 0 < count($terms) ) {

    // Get first term in array
    $first_term = $terms[0]->term_id;

    // Create a string to represent hierarchy of terms
    // get_taxonomy_parents() is a custom function that returns a string formatted as `$tax_parent . $separator . $tax_child . $separator` etc.
    $media_type = get_taxonomy_parents( $first_term, 'media-type', false, '/', true );

    // Remove everything after second `/` character (we only want to go two levels deep into the tax hierarchy)
    if ( 2 < substr_count( $media_type, '/' ) ) {
      $media_type = substr( $media_type, 0, strpos( $media_type, '/', strpos( $media_type, '/') + 1 ) );
    }

    // Remove trailing slash
    $media_type = trim( $media_type, '/' );

  } else {
    // Set default
    $media_type = 'articles';
  }
  // Encode for URL usage, but preserve slashes
  $media_type = str_replace( '%2F', '/' , urlencode($media_type) );

  $link = str_replace( '%media_type%', $media_type , $link );

  return $link;
}
```